# Symfony on Synology

Tags: php, symfony, synology

I use the latest DSM on my synology (DS415+), DSM 6.1.3-15152 Update 4, and I try to install a new Symfony application, but it doesn't work.

I tried:

> symfony new ProjectName

but it ends up with:

> ✕  Symfony 3.3.9 was successfully installed but your system doesn't meet its
>        technical requirements! Fix the following issues before executing
>        your Symfony application:
>
> - token_get_all() must be available
>     Install and enable the Tokenizer extension.

Then I tried:

> composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ProjectName

The install process ends up fine, but after running this command:

> php bin/symfony_requirements

It's the same Tokenizer extension issue

I also tried:

> php56 symfony.phar new ProjectName

Same as the previous install command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm having my own issues with Symfony on DSM6, very frustrating!

Synology decided to build their own PHP packet from source. They choose to remove some capabilities and extensions (including the tokenizer) from their build. That's why you can't run Symfony with their PHP version as this doesn't meet the symfony requirements.

But in your case, you should continue using php56 (version 5.6) instead of php (version 7). So change

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

To

```
php56 bin/symfony_requirements
```

I'm pretty sure you're not out of the woods yet.

Comment: @LeFauve Glad I could help. Did you manage to get everything up and running after that?

Comment: Yes, I confirm, everything is working fine now on my synology.